# Post-process a rendered django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Let's say I have a basic custom template tag written for django. And in my template, let's say I use it as such:

```
{% do_something "x" %}
{% do_something "y" %}
{% do_something "z" %}
```

`do_something` needs to fetch information from a model, i.e. the database, which gets rendered by the tag. Am I correct in assuming that every time i add a call to `do_something` in my template, django will make a call to my database?

If so, I'd like to find an alternative solution, the only solution I can think of being:

Write a "Response Postprocessor" middleware which would parse the rendered response to look for some kind of placeholders, say `__x__`, `__y__` etc, collate them, perform a single, grouped query, and then replace the placeholders with the relevant content.

This seems rather "hacky" to me, it just doesn't feel right. Is this my only option?

Comment: I don't know what do_something does but, the way it is written, can you do something like `{% do_something "x", "y", "z" %}` where do_something would render everything for all 3? That way, If you do your logic in the template_tag right, you would only hit the database once.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: please don't do the hack you proposed, it seems very error-prone and smelly.

Anyway the answer very much depends on what does `do_something` actually do. If it is somehow accessing template context where you have stored the model **instance** then no, Django won't hit database more than once if the model is already fetched from server - the data from db are stored in `instance.__dict__`.

But if the `do_something` logic does not work with the template context and instead has its own logic than yes - it will be called more once. You can use caching tools like https://pythonhosted.org/django-memoize/ but in your case caching will only work for that user case only if you call the function with the same arguments. Which is not the case - you are calling it with x,y,z...

You could make cached function that access the database **if the database logic is same for x,y,z calls** and than call this function from within the template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just cache in some way objects that your template tag is using when is first called, so next calls can re-use them. Template tags are getting context variable, you can add here your 'cached' objects as variable.